# Is there any limitation for the number of threads to service RPC calls?

Tags: json-rpc

Bitcoin has the config. How about ethereum? (geth)

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin

```
-rpcthreads=<n> Set the number of threads to service RPC calls (default: 4)
```

Comment: i don't think ethereum has the same option. check https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC

Comment: @BadrBellaj thank you! as you said, seems it does not have the option.

Answer (score 1):

Parity has the `--jsonrpc-threads` commandline parameter